# Opening a list of URLs and splitting the queries into different files

Tags: python, parsing, generics, url, file

I recently made a program in Python to open a list of URLs and split the queries into different files. I want to make this code more generic and simple. I am open to suggestions.

```
def parse_file():
    # Open the file for reading
    infile = open("URLlist.txt", 'r')
    # Read every single line of the file into an array of lines
    lines = infile.readlines()
    # For every line in the array of lines, do something with that line
    for line in lines: # for every line in lines. 
        print line # print the URL
        # parse the URL query string list
        # if the URL has a query component print out the the first
        # argument(k) and if the URL has multiple arguments, print out
        # the other arguments. (v)
        for k,v in urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlparse(line).query): 
            print k, v

            if k == "blog": # if the printed out arguements have blog in it
                           # write it out to the apropriate file and do this
                           # to all the others.
                with open('blog_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'p':
                with open('p_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'attachment_id':
                with open('attachment_id_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'lang':
                with open('lang_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'portfolio':
                with open('portfolio_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'page_id':
                with open('page_id_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'comments_popup':
                with open('comments_popup_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'iframe':
                with open('iframe_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'width':
                with open('width_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
            elif k == 'height':
                with open('height_file.txt'.format(),'a') as f:
                    f.write(v)
                print "--------------------"
    infile.close()
    f.close()
parse_file()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Before We Get Started

It would be good if you could provide some examples of the URLs that you are looking to parse, I did a cursory search and I couldn't coerce a query result from any that I tried with:

```
urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlparse("some_url").query
```

In the interest of brevity I'll assume you have some set of URLs that this is working for.

## Code Review

Step one in making your code more generic will be to remove the hard-coded URL text file from your function body. I would suggest it be a parameter to the **parse_file** function.

Also, You don't need to do this:

```
lines = infile.readlines()
for line in lines:
```

[**.readlines()**](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) isn't necessary in how it is being used here and the file can be read without it. You obviously know about the [With Statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) and how to use it as a context manager - but you're still opening and closing your URL list file manually!

```
infile = open("URLlist.txt", 'r')
...
infile.close()
```

Instead, you can alias the opened file in your With Statement and it will be iterable without **.readlines()**:

```
with open(input_file) as input:
    for line in input:
```

Also, if you find yourself using multiple If/Elif clauses you might consider it time to look into some of Python's more interesting data structures, below I'm using a dictionary. 
You can replace your predicate:

```
if k == 'blog':
```

and instead use a key in a dictionary with the value corresponding to the the subsequent procedure.

```
{'blog' : "blog_file.txt"}
```

## Revision

Below is a possible revision to your code:

```
import urlparse
def parse_file(input_file):
    tags = {'blog' : "blog_file.txt",
            'p' : "p_file.txt",
            'attachment_id' : "attachment_id_file.txt",
            'lang' : "lang_file.txt",
            'portfolio' : "portfolio_file.txt",
            'page_id' : "page_id_file.txt",
            'comments_popup' : "comments_popup_file.txt",
            'iframe' : "iframe_file.txt",
            'width' : "width_file.txt",
            'height' : "height_file.txt"}
    with open(input_file) as input:
        for line in input:
            parsed_url = urlparse.parse_qsl(urlparse.urlparse(line).query)
            if len(parsed_url) > 0:
                for key, value in parsed_url:
                    if key in tags:
                        with open(tags[key], 'a') as output_file:
                            output_file.write(value)
                    else:
                        print key + " not in tags."
            else:
                print(line + " does not yield query.")
```

I think this should work as you describe, but without a set of example URLs it's difficult to say for sure. The line:

```
if len(parsed_url) > 0:
```

is used here because I couldn't coerce **.query** to return anything but an empty list on those URLs I attempted.

## Final Thought

It might be a good idea to change the functionality for those keys not found in your *tags* dictionary. You might consider creating a miscellaneous, or catch-all file that unmatched values get written to. That way you don't totally lose work on those unmatched URLs.

*This is all based on the assumption that you have some domain that your code is currently working for.*